# validation error message did not show correctly for related inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

my validation error message didnot show correctly.for example I insert value on Name input but validation error message of email was shown or when I insert value on phone input,validation of email was shown.I want when I insert value in specific input only the validation error message of it was shown.

```
    <form class="contactForm" onsubmit="return validateContactForm();">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name" class="label-login">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <span id="namespan" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="label-login">email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <span id="emailspan" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="phone" class="label-login">tell number </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <span id="tellspan" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message" class="label-login label-message">message</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="message" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
                                    <span id="messagespan" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-send center-block" value="send/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
              $(document).ready(function () {            
            $(".contactForm input,.contactForm textarea").each(function () {
               $(this).keyup(function () {
            var pt = /^[\w.]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i;

            if (!pt.test($("#email").val())) {    
                $("#emailspan").html("insert email correctly");
            }
            else { 
                $("#emailspan").text("");

            }
            if ($("#name").val().length < 3) {
                $("#namespan").html("insert name correctly");
            }
            else {
                $("#namespan").text("");
            }
            if ($("#phone").val().length < 12) {
                $("#tellspan").html("insert phone correctly");
            }
            else {
                $("#tellspan").text("");
            }
            if ($("#message").val().trim().length < 3) {
                $("#messagespan").html("insert message correctly");
            }
            else {
                $("#messagespan").text("");
            }
        });
    });
 });
  function validateContactForm() {
    var bool = true;
    var pt = /^[\w.]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i;
    if (!pt.test($("#email").val())) {
        bool = false;
        $("#emailspan").html("insert email correctly");
    }

    if ($("#name").val().length < 3) {
        bool = false;
        $("#namespan").html("insert name correctly");
    }
    if ($("#phone").val().length < 12 ) {
        bool = false;
        $("#tellspan").html("insert tell correctly");
    }
    if ($("#message").val().trim().length < 3) {
        bool = false;
        $("#messageSpan").html("insert message correctly");
    }

    return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some issue in the form and updated here

Form send button does not close properly

`.contactFormnot` not added on form tag

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".contactForm input,.contactForm textarea").each(function () {
  $(this).keyup(function () {
   var pt = /^[\w.]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i;
   if (!pt.test($("#email").val())) {
    $("#emailspan").html("insert email correctly");
   } else {
    $("#emailspan").text("");
   }
   if ($("#name").val().length < 3) {
    $("#namespan").html("insert name correctly");
   } else {
    $("#namespan").text("");
   }
   if ($("#phone").val().length < 12) {
    $("#tellspan").html("insert phone correctly");
   } else {
    $("#tellspan").text("");
   }
   if ($("#message").val().trim().length < 3) {
    $("#messagespan").html("insert message correctly");
   } else {
    $("#messagespan").text("");
   }
  });
 });
});
function validateContactForm() {
 var bool = true;
 var pt = /^[\w.]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i;
 if (!pt.test($("#email").val())) {
  bool = false;
  $("#emailspan").html("insert email correctly");
 }
 if ($("#name").val().length < 3) {
  bool = false;
  $("#namespan").html("insert name correctly");
 }
 if ($("#phone").val().length < 12) {
  bool = false;
  $("#tellspan").html("insert tell correctly");
 }
 if ($("#message").val().trim().length < 3) {
  bool = false;
  $("#messageSpan").html("insert message correctly");
 }
 return bool;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="contactForm" onsubmit="return validateContactForm();">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name" class="label-login">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <span id="namespan" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="label-login">email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <span id="emailspan" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="phone" class="label-login">tell number </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <span id="tellspan" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message" class="label-login label-message">message</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="message" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
                                    <span id="messagespan" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-send center-block" value="send" />
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You always make validations all together. So whenever a keyup is made on any field, all validations take place.
To avoid this you can proceed in at least 2 ways.

Way 1

You can check the id of the element which fired the event and validate only  that field logic. You'll mantain an unique function, adding an if for each field validation

Ex.

```
      $(".contactForm input,.contactForm textarea").each(function () {
           $(this).keyup(function () {
        var pt = /^[\w.]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}/i;
        var id=$(this).attr("id");

        if(id==="email"){
         if (!pt.test($("#email").val())) {    
            $("#emailspan").html("insert email correctly");
          }
          else { 
            $("#emailspan").text("");
         }
        }
        ...
```

and so on for each field..

Way 2

Alternatively you can make and handler function for each specific field, removing `$(".contactForm input,.contactForm textarea").each(function () {`.

Ex.

```
 $("#name").keyup(function () {
  if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
            $("#namespan").html("insert name correctly");
        }
        else {
            $("#namespan").text("");
        }
 });
 .....
```

and so on for each field